# How to use set offset for only 1 of the datasources in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot two datasources together in gnuplot: one from a datafile, using text as x-data (with xticlabels and errorbars) and another a constant.

I don't want the xticlabels to reach the sides of the graph, so I use "set offset". However, I *do* want the constant to reach the sides of the graph.

An example gnuplot script:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 500, 500
file = 'data.txt'
set output 'plot.png'
set xtics rotate by -45
set yrange [0:1]
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0

plot file using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars notitle,\
0.5 notitle
```

With the associated data.txt file:

```
"Europe"    0.4 0.03
"North America" 0.8 0.05
"South America" 0.1 0.08
"Asia"  0.7 0.01
"Africa"    0.9 0.03
"Australia" 0.2 0.03
```

Provides the following plot:
[image: Plot with constant function not reaching left/right edges]

However, I want the following plot:
[image: Plot with constant function reaching left/right edges]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result if you are simply setting the `xrange[]` properly.
In your case when using  `xticlabels(1)`, Europe=0 and Australia=5.
So, simply set `xrange[-0.5:5.5]`. If the number of items (here 6) is unknown beforehand you could get it either via `|$Data|` or `stats $Data` and `STATS_records`.

**Code:**

```
### border when using xticlabels()
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"Europe"    0.4 0.03
"North America" 0.8 0.05
"South America" 0.1 0.08
"Asia"  0.7 0.01
"Africa"    0.9 0.03
"Australia" 0.2 0.03
EOD

set xtics rotate by -45

set xrange [-0.5:5.5]
set yrange [0:1]

plot $Data using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars notitle,\
    0.5 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the constant as headless arrow:

```
set arrow from graph 0, first 0.5 to graph 1, first 0.5 nohead lt 1
```